# Can't publish test results to TFS 2010 with NUnit4TeamBuild

Tags: tfs, nunit, tfsbuild, xunit

I have an xUnit test suite developed in VS 2015 that I'm trying to publish results back to TFS 2010 after running them during the build.

It's running the tests, transforming the xUnit results xml to NUnit results xml but I get exceptions when it tries to publish it back to TFS.

I'm using **NUnit for Team Build (http://nunit4teambuild.codeplex.com/)** Version 2.0 and this is the exception I'm getting during the build:

```
System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not find file 'xUnit.net Tests'.
 File name: 'xUnit.net Tests'
 at System.IO.__Error.WinIOError(Int32 errorCode, String maybeFullPath)
 at System.IO.FileInfo.get_Length()
 at KWatkins.NUnitTfs.Tfs2010.Publisher2010.<>c__DisplayClassc.<UpdateTestRunWithTmiRunAndAssemblies>b__9(FileInfo file) in C:\Users\Kevin Watkins\Documents\Visual Studio 10\Projects\NUnitTFS\NUnitTFS\Tfs2010\Publisher2010.cs:line 150
 at System.Linq.Enumerable.WhereSelectArrayIterator`2.MoveNext()
 at System.Linq.Buffer`1..ctor(IEnumerable`1 source)
 at System.Linq.Enumerable.ToArrayTSource
 at KWatkins.NUnitTfs.Tfs2010.Publisher2010.UpdateTestRunWithTmiRunAndAssemblies(TestRun testRun, XDocument trx) in C:\Users\Kevin Watkins\Documents\Visual Studio 10\Projects\NUnitTFS\NUnitTFS\Tfs2010\Publisher2010.cs:line 149
 at KWatkins.NUnitTfs.Tfs2010.Publisher2010.PublishToTfs(XDocument trx) in C:\Users\Kevin Watkins\Documents\Visual Studio 10\Projects\NUnitTFS\NUnitTFS\Tfs2010\Publisher2010.cs:line 44
 at KWatkins.NUnitTfs.Program.Main(String[] args) in C:\Users\Kevin Watkins\Documents\Visual Studio 10\Projects\NUnitTFS\NUnitTFS\Program.cs:line 29
```

**Note:** I am ***not*** Kevin Watson. I believe he's the developer of the NUnitTfs stuff and those paths in the exception aren't mine. I don't know what file it's trying to access nor why it can't find it.

If you want to look at the code/classes/line numbers that the errors are referring to, you can look at the NUnit for Team Build source code here: http://nunit4teambuild.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#NUnitTFS/NUnitTFS/Tfs2010/Publisher2010.cs

Comment: Can you share the detail log here?

Comment: @starianchen-MSFT the log doesn't show anything else. Just the same as I copied above